# OpenCV greyscale image to vector

Tags: opencv, vector, matrix, grayscale

I want to save my grayscale image of type `Mat` into a list of vectors. They greyscale image contains values such as `110`, `123`, `150`, etc... and when I use my code to transfer the data into a list of vectors and after I have transfered the data, I print the items in the list of vectors and they are values such as `-155552323` or `75694920`. Where have my nice `110`, `123`, `150` from before gone??

```
cv::Mat grayscaleFrame;
cv::Mat image;
image = cv::imread(fullPath);

        cvtColor(image, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);
        cout << grayscaleFrame << endl;

        vector<int> **vectorList = new vector<int>*[grayscaleFrame.rows];

        for(size_t i=0; i<grayscaleFrame.rows;i++)
        {
            int *p = grayscaleFrame.ptr<int>(i); // pointer to row 0
            std::vector<int> row(p, p+grayscaleFrame.cols); 
            vectorList[i]=&row;

            for(int a =0; a<vectorList[i]->size();a++)
            {
                cout << vectorList[i]->at(a) << endl;
            }

        }
```

If my mistake is to use `&row` then how can I accomplish this without addressing the address, because when I remove the `&` I get the error: "No suitable conversion function from ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in int type of vector elements, they shuld be unsigned char.

But when you print it use cout << (int)your_value << endl;